# Was this the right SE site for this question?

Tags: discussion

https://superuser.com/questions/883551/smtp-dns-validation-with-multiple-mail-servers-behind-multiple-public-ips

I was debating between that and Stack Overflow, and maybe even Network Engineering (my home community), although I couldn't find a definitive answer on whether DNS is considered in scope over there.

If there was a better place for this question, where would it be?

**Edit:** Thanks for the suggestions guys, I've [re-posted it at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/673961/smtp-dns-validation-with-multiple-mail-servers-behind-multiple-public-ips).  Feel free to delete my post on Super User.  Or I guess I can in a few days (once Thor is given a chance to see my response to him).

Comment: I'd probably say Serverfault (http://serverfault.com) might be the appropriate place.

Comment: I see nothing in that question that would be on topic at Stackoverflow, your question, has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: This is definitely on-topic here. Whether this is where it will get the best response, I don't know. I'd agree maybe serverfault. Or, *maybe* infosec.

Comment: Seems like an IT question to me (which would be off-topic at SU).  I'd go with serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reposting, you could have flagged it for migration - anyway I have refunded the bounty and closed it now.